# CascadingDropDown from XML in a Dataset

Tags: c#, asp.net, xml, dataset

I've tried to get this working in so many ways and I'm getting frustrated because none of them work. This is the closest I've gotten. I'm trying to populate three cascading drop downs from an XML file. I've tried different XML configurations and am still not sure if the one I'm using is correct. The third dropdown only gets populated if a specific selection is made from the second dropdown. Otherwise it should be inactive.

The first dropdown populates fine but the second is blank after being enabled.

Here's my aspx code:

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="CascadingDropDownList.aspx.cs" Inherits="CSASPNETCascadingDropDownList.CascadingDropDownListWithPostBack" EnableEventValidation="false" %>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head id="Head1" runat="server">
    <title>View CascadingDropDownList With PostBack</title>
    <%-- The follow javascript is the work around of EventValidation in FireFox --%>

<script type="text/javascript">
    var hdfDdl = null; // Save city dropdownlist selected option
    var ddlJobTitle2 = null;

    // Restore the selected option in city dropdownlist when page is rendering
    window.onload = function () {
        hdfDdl = document.getElementById('hdfDdlJobTitle2SelectedIndex');
        ddlJobTitle2 = document.getElementById('ddlJobTitle2');
        ddlJobTitle2.selectedIndex = hdfDdl.value;
        EnableOrDisableButton(false);
    }

    // Save city dropdownlist selected option when selected option is changed in city dropdownlist
    function onChange() {
        hdfDdl.value = ddlJobTitle2.selectedIndex;
    }

    // Enable or diasble submit button
    function EnableOrDisableButton(ToF) {
        document.getElementById('Button1').disabled = ToF;
    }
</script>

</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
       <table class="style2">
        <tr>
          <td style="width:20px"></td>
          <td style="width:440px" colspan="2"> Place of Employment</td>
          <td> Professional Affiliation</td>
          <td> Specialty</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td style="width:20px">&nbsp;</td>
          <td colspan="2"><asp:DropDownList runat="server" id="ddlOrg" style="width:220px" AutoPostBack="true" OnSelectedIndexChanged="ddlOrg_SelectedIndexChanged">
            </asp:DropDownList>
            <br /><asp:Label ID="LabelOrg" runat="server"></asp:Label>
            </td>
          <td><asp:DropDownList runat="server" id="ddlJobTitle1" style="width:220px" AutoPostBack="true" OnSelectedIndexChanged="ddlJobTitle1_SelectedIndexChanged">
              </asp:DropDownList>
            <br />
                          <asp:Label ID="LabelJobTitle1" runat="server"></asp:Label>
           </td>
          <td><asp:DropDownList runat="server" id="ddlJobTitle2" onChange="onChange()" style="width:220px">
            </asp:DropDownList>
            <br />
            <asp:Label ID="LabelJobTitle2" runat="server"></asp:Label></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td style="width:20px"></td>
          <td style="width:220px"><asp:HiddenField runat="server" id="hdfDdlOrgSelectedIndex"></asp:HiddenField><br /><div id="OrgVal"></div></td>
          <td style="width:220px"></td>
          <td><asp:HiddenField runat="server"  id="hdfDdlJobTitle1SelectedIndex"></asp:HiddenField><br /><div id="JobTItle1Val"></div></td>
          <td><asp:HiddenField runat="server"  id="hdfDdlJobTitle2SelectedIndex"></asp:HiddenField><br /><div id="JobTitle2Val"></div>

          </td>
        </tr>
           </table>
               <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Submit" OnClick="Button1_Click"
            Width="66px" />
        <br />
        <br />
        <asp:Label ID="LabelResult" runat="server"></asp:Label>
     </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Here's the cs code behind file:

```
using System;
using System.Data;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;

namespace CSASPNETCascadingDropDownList
{
    public partial class CascadingDropDownListWithPostBack : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// Page Load event
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="sender"></param>
        /// <param name="e"></param>
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (!IsPostBack)
            {

                PopulateDDLFromXMLFile();  

                //Bind Org dropdownlist
                //BindddlOrg();
                ddlJobTitle1.Enabled = false;
                ddlJobTitle2.Enabled = false;

                // Insert one item to dropdownlist top
                ddlJobTitle1.Items.Insert(0, new ListItem("Select JobTitle1", "-1"));
                ddlJobTitle2.Items.Insert(0, new ListItem("Select JobTitle2", "-1"));

                // Initialize JobTitle2 dropdownlist selected index
                hdfDdlJobTitle2SelectedIndex.Value = "0";
            }
        }

        //populates the dropdownlist from xml file  
        public void PopulateDDLFromXMLFile()
        {
            DataSet ds = new DataSet();
            ds.ReadXml(MapPath("App_Data") + "\\XMLFile1.xml");

            //get the dataview of tables, which is default table name  
            DataView dv = ds.Tables["organization"].DefaultView;
            DataView dj = ds.Tables["job"].DefaultView;
            DataView dp = ds.Tables["specialty"].DefaultView;
            //or we can use:  
            //DataView dv = ds.Tables[0].DefaultView;  

            //Now sort the DataView by column name "Name"  
           // dv.Sort = "Name";

            //now define datatext field and datavalue field of dropdownlist  
            ddlOrg.DataTextField = "name";
            ddlOrg.DataValueField = "value";
            ddlJobTitle1.DataTextField = "name";
            ddlJobTitle1.DataValueField = "value";
            ddlJobTitle2.DataTextField = "name";
            ddlJobTitle2.DataValueField = "value";

            //now bind the dropdownlist to the dataview  
            ddlOrg.DataSource = dv;
            ddlOrg.DataBind();
            ddlJobTitle1.DataSource = dj;
            ddlJobTitle1.DataBind();
            ddlJobTitle2.DataSource = dp;
            ddlJobTitle2.DataBind();

            //insert new list item as helper
            ddlOrg.Items.Insert(0, new ListItem("Select Organisation", "-1"));
            ddlJobTitle1.Items.Insert(0, new ListItem("Select Professional Affiliation", "-1"));
            ddlJobTitle2.Items.Insert(0, new ListItem("Select Specialty", "-1"));



        }  


        /// <summary>
        /// Bind Org dropdownlist
        /// </summary>

        protected void ddlOrg_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Bind();
        }

        private void Bind()
        {
            DataSet ds = new DataSet();
            ds.ReadXml(Server.MapPath("App_Data") + "\\XMLFile1.xml");
            ddlJobTitle1.DataTextField = "name";
            ddlJobTitle1.DataValueField = "value";
            DataView view = new DataView(ds.Tables["job"]);
            view.RowFilter = "value='" + ddlOrg.SelectedValue + "'";
            ddlJobTitle1.Enabled = true;
            ddlJobTitle1.DataSource = view;
            ddlJobTitle1.DataBind();
        } 

        /// <summary>
        /// JobTitle1 dropdownlist SelectedIndexChanged event
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="sender"></param>
        /// <param name="e"></param>
        protected void ddlJobTitle1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            // Bind JobTitle2 dropdownlist based on JobTitle1 value
            string strJobTitle1 = string.Empty;
            strJobTitle1 = ddlJobTitle1.SelectedValue;
            DataSet ds = new DataSet();
            ds.ReadXml(Server.MapPath("App_Data") + "\\XMLFile1.xml");
            ddlJobTitle1.DataTextField = "name";
            ddlJobTitle1.DataValueField = "value";
            DataView view = new DataView(ds.Tables["specialty"]);
            view.RowFilter = "value='" + ddlJobTitle1.SelectedValue + "'";
            ddlJobTitle2.Items.Clear();
            ddlJobTitle2.DataSource = view;
            ddlJobTitle2.DataBind();
            ddlJobTitle2.Items.Insert(0, new ListItem("Select Specialty", "-1"));

            // Initialize JobTitle2 dropdownlist selected index
            hdfDdlJobTitle2SelectedIndex.Value = "0";

            // Enable JobTitle2 dropdownlist when it has items

                ddlJobTitle2.Enabled = true;

       }

      /// <summary>
             /// Show selected value
             /// </summary>
             /// <param name="sender"></param>
             /// <param name="e"></param>
             protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
             {
                 // Get the selected index of JobTitle2 dropdownlist
                 int iJobTitle2Selected = Convert.ToInt16(hdfDdlJobTitle2SelectedIndex.Value);

                 // The result will be showing
                 string strResult = string.Empty;
                 if (ddlOrg.SelectedIndex == 0)
                 {
                     strResult = "Please select a Org.";
                 }
                 else if (ddlJobTitle1.SelectedIndex == 0 && strResult == string.Empty)
                 {
                     strResult = "Please select a Professional Affiliation";
                 }
                 else if (hdfDdlJobTitle2SelectedIndex.Value == "0" && strResult == string.Empty)
                 {
                     strResult = "Please select a Specialty.";
                 }
                 else
                 {
                     strResult = "You selected Org: " + ddlOrg.SelectedValue
                         + " ; JobTitle1: " + ddlJobTitle1.SelectedValue
                         + " ; JobTitle2: " + ddlJobTitle2.Items[iJobTitle2Selected].Value;
                 }

                 LabelResult.Text = strResult;
             }
    }
}
```

Here's the XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<dropdowns>
  <organizations>
    <organization>
      <value>A0EAD6A8813E474B9F9A3E0C64D72F61</value>
      <name>Hospital</name>
    </organization>
    <organization>
      <value>DD8BE886FA18401E9CF30AC64B49ACD8</value>
      <name>Sleep Lab</name>
    </organization>
    <organization>
      <value>F8182C928BE14239A576895D39591D38</value>
      <name>Ventilation Home Service</name>
    </organization>
    <organization>
      <value>E3865431ECF9499692E79DBF2FBAA3B2</value>
      <name>Community Health Centre</name>
    </organization>
    <organization>
      <value>711AA0D43D6346FC9AD38659D9CB8840</value>
      <name>Home Care Provider</name>
    </organization>
    <organization>
      <value>D54FAE898ECF4AB4A92B99C5AA536910</value>
      <name>ResMed</name>
    </organization>
    <organization>
      <value>4E44CDB4F7E5426E99368194BBB73282</value>
      <name>Other</name>
    </organization>
  </organizations>
  <jobs>
    <job_organization name="Hospital">
      <job>
        <value>-2</value>
        <name>Physician</name>
      </job>
      <job>
        <value>111AEF6C39984713AA10E6F1D051F97E</value>
        <name>Nurse</name>
      </job>
      <job>
        <value>90CF5DB3D06A4B759F21A3F20B5F5DD4</value>
        <name>Physiologist</name>
      </job>
      <job>
        <value>55F8C6537718420DB6E4E3A7C087D540</value>
        <name>Physiotherapist</name>
      </job>
      <job>
        <value>884EB090E9B7469DA3CA8BA2D6FC4F4E</value>
        <name>Biomedical Engineer/Technician</name>
      </job>
      <job>
        <value>C2383AA850534CD9A4E03019386AA56C</value>
        <name>Administrator</name>
      </job>
      <job>
        <value>C8997E78569A4410956E5E7C6C1D57F2</value>
        <name>Manager</name>
      </job>
      <job>
        <value>5196E883DF614A319A3CDF4573C3E858</value>
        <name>Supplies/Procurement</name>
      </job>
    </job_organization>
    <job_organization name="Sleep Lab">
      <job>
        <value>D59C926B83A04E5297112FB599A8715F</value>
        <name>Physician</name>
      </job>
      <job>
        <value>111AEF6C39984713AA10E6F1D051F97E</value>
        <name>Nurse</name>
      </job>
      <job>
        <value>90CF5DB3D06A4B759F21A3F20B5F5DD4</value>
        <name>Physiologist</name>
      </job>
      <job>
        <value>3A5AAA4E5D474F3AAFC24D46B63BA073</value>
        <name>Respiratory Technician</name>
      </job>
      <job>
        <value>C2383AA850534CD9A4E03019386AA56C</value>
        <name>Administrator</name>
      </job>
      <job>
        <value>C8997E78569A4410956E5E7C6C1D57F2</value>
        <name>Manager</name>
      </job>
      <job>
        <value>ML.BASE.job.None</value>
        <name>Other</name>
    </job>
    </job_organization>
    <job_organization name="Ventilation Home Service">
      <job>
        <value>D59C926B83A04E5297112FB599A8715F</value>
        <name>Physician</name>
      </job>
      <job>
        <value>111AEF6C39984713AA10E6F1D051F97E</value>
        <name>Nurse</name>
      </job>
      <job>
        <value>55F8C6537718420DB6E4E3A7C087D540</value>
        <name>Physiotherapist</name>
      </job>
      <job>
        <value>3A5AAA4E5D474F3AAFC24D46B63BA073</value>
        <name>Respiratory Technician</name>
      </job>
      <job>
        <value>6E0D7BE08120464381FD70F4E07EAB4E</value>
        <name>Care Assistant</name>
      </job>
      <job>
        <value>C2383AA850534CD9A4E03019386AA56C</value>
        <name>Administrator</name>
      </job>
      <job>
        <value>F2D6388FF4CE49CDBFDEAB7D9DBEE9CF</value>
        <name>Biomedical Engineer</name>
      </job>
      <job>
        <value>C8997E78569A4410956E5E7C6C1D57F2</value>
        <name>Manager</name>
      </job>
      <job>
        <value>ML.BASE.job.None</value>
        <name>Other</name>
      </job>
    </job_organization>
    <job_organization name="Community Health Centre">
      <job>
        <value>D59C926B83A04E5297112FB599A8715F</value>
        <name>Physician</name>
      </job>
      <job>
        <value>318560B544674C2994131543FE67FF5E</value>
        <name>Dentist</name>
      </job>
      <job>
        <value>111AEF6C39984713AA10E6F1D051F97E</value>
        <name>Nurse</name>
      </job>
      <job>
        <value>C65378247CC6484BA56228E8102B5A1B</value>
        <name>Technician</name>
      </job>
      <job>
        <value>C2383AA850534CD9A4E03019386AA56C</value>
        <name>Administrator</name>
      </job>
      <job>
        <value>C8997E78569A4410956E5E7C6C1D57F2</value>
        <name>Manager</name>
      </job>
      <job>
        <value>ML.BASE.job.None</value>
        <name>Other</name>
      </job>
    </job_organization>
    <job_organization name="Home Care Provider">
      <job>
        <value>D59C926B83A04E5297112FB599A8715F</value>
        <name>Physician</name>
      </job>
      <job>
        <value>111AEF6C39984713AA10E6F1D051F97E</value>
        <name>Nurse</name>
      </job>
      <job>
        <value>55F8C6537718420DB6E4E3A7C087D540</value>
        <name>Physiotherapist</name>
      </job>
      <job>
        <value>C65378247CC6484BA56228E8102B5A1B</value>
        <name>Technician</name>
      </job>
      <job>
        <value>6E0D7BE08120464381FD70F4E07EAB4E</value>
        <name>Care Assistant</name>
      </job>
      <job>
        <value>C2383AA850534CD9A4E03019386AA56C</value>
        <name>Administrator</name>
      </job>
      <job>
        <value>C8997E78569A4410956E5E7C6C1D57F2</value>
        <name>Manager</name>
      </job>
      <job>
        <value>ML.BASE.job.None</value>
        <name>Other</name>
      </job>
    </job_organization>
    <job_organization name="ResMed">
      <job>
        <value>D59C926B83A04E5297112FB599A8715F</value>
        <name>Physician</name>
      </job>
      <job>
        <value>111AEF6C39984713AA10E6F1D051F97E</value>
        <name>Nurse</name>
      </job>
      <job>
        <value>55F8C6537718420DB6E4E3A7C087D540</value>
        <name>Physiotherapist</name>
      </job>
      <job>
        <value>C65378247CC6484BA56228E8102B5A1B</value>
        <name>Technician</name>
      </job>
      <job>
        <value>49CE2F9D94FA4A488D49B551C6C1A1DF</value>
        <name>Salesperson</name>
      </job>
      <job>
        <value>51ACA74CB1D74BD890AB19260C188FE8</value>
        <name>Product Manager</name>
      </job>
      <job>
        <value>C2383AA850534CD9A4E03019386AA56C</value>
        <name>Admin</name>
      </job>
      <job>
        <value>C8997E78569A4410956E5E7C6C1D57F2</value>
        <name>Manager</name>
      </job>
      <job>
        <value>EAAD4174C6AC48B19D90949289AB8A39</value>
        <name>Authorised ResMed Distributor</name>
      </job>
      <job>
        <value>ML.BASE.job.None</value>
        <name>Other</name>
      </job>
    </job_organization>
    <job_organization name="Other">
      <job>
        <value>5196E883DF614A319A3CDF4573C3E858</value>
        <name>Supplies/Procurement</name>
      </job>
    </job_organization>
  </jobs>
  <specialties>
    <specialty_job value="-2">
      <specialty>
        <value>E5B838C3AA304813B3EA4E28EE33702F</value>
        <name>Anesthesiologist</name>
      </specialty>
      <specialty>
        <value>36C9F22DC54347CEA39C142FE91E8B36</value>
        <name>A and E</name>
      </specialty>
      <specialty>
        <value>35E798C18DC04ECFB022DCF0E6DBEB51</value>
        <name>Cardiologist</name>
      </specialty>
      <specialty>
        <value>343B2555E45142E096546A3781680C02</value>
        <name>Dental Surgeon</name>
      </specialty>
      <specialty>
        <value>A5C669F6DB4D41DA8409960D6952023C</value>
        <name>Diabetologist/Endocrinologist</name>
      </specialty>
      <specialty>
        <value>2B01B4C29253459797CB596FE81C3AF4</value>
        <name>ENT</name>
      </specialty>
      <specialty>
        <value>6C761F3F81CB421BBD0746914031EF19</value>
        <name>General Medicine</name>
      </specialty>
      <specialty>
        <value>9DB49A58B8484E73AA24227DCDAD4C96</value>
        <name>Intensivist</name>
      </specialty>
      <specialty>
        <value>F80D023B174A421A82A140691BCD9E22</value>
        <name>Neurologist</name>
      </specialty>
      <specialty>
        <value>3F95529E15764EB1A55255DCEDDB6C4A</value>
        <name>Pediatrician</name>
      </specialty>
      <specialty>
        <value>9FC573D63A884C04A8675E86B43EABB9</value>
        <name>Psychiatrist</name>
      </specialty>
      <specialty>
        <value>7230D95FE4844A7785D25A73D5240BB9</value>
        <name>Respiratory</name>
      </specialty>
      <specialty>
        <value>E784A9F594BF468D85C51BBD5A9B0F5D</value>
        <name>Trainee</name>
      </specialty>
      <specialty>
        <value>431614E6148A4F639F912ED08803BD79</value>
        <name>Other Physician</name>
      </specialty>
    </specialty_job>
  </specialties>
</dropdowns>
```

What's preventing the second dropdown from populating?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is your first DropDownList has a selected value which should not be in "job" table table you are filtering. You should change the code to this:

```
private void Bind()
{
    int jobOrganizationId = 0;
    DataSet ds = new DataSet();
    ds.ReadXml(Server.MapPath("App_Data") + "\\XMLFile1.xml");
    DataRow[]  rows = ds.Tables["job_organization"].Select("name = '" + ddlOrg.SelectedItem.Text + "'");
    if(rows.Length > 0 && int.TryParse(rows[0]["job_organization_Id"].ToString(), out jobOrganizationId))
    {
        ddlJobTitle1.DataTextField = "name";
        ddlJobTitle1.DataValueField = "value";
        DataView view = new DataView(ds.Tables["job"]);
        view.RowFilter = "job_organization_Id='" + jobOrganizationId.ToString() + "'";
        ddlJobTitle1.Enabled = true;
        ddlJobTitle1.DataSource = view;
        ddlJobTitle1.DataBind();
    }
}
```

I would recommend to utilize the DataSet Viewer in Visual studio.It is very handy when you generate dataset from xml.

Comment: Solved! I used your code as the basis for the SelectedIndexChanged event for the third dropdown as well.